# font-size depending on character length?

Tags: php, html, css, font-size, text-justify

Is it possible to change the div's font-size depending on how many characters are in it? I have image album titles in small fixed width div's (100px). Sometimes the album names have too many characters that they force a new line. So I was wondering if it is possible to re-size the font to keep the title on one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, by assigning a variable to a class:

In your css:

```
.longstring {
  font-size: 10pt;
}
.shortstring {
  font-size: 14pt;
}
```

In your view

```
<?php
$random_number = '42';
if(strlen($div_string)>$random_number){
    $font_class = 'longstring';
}else{
    $font_class = 'shortstring';
}?>
<div class="<?php echo $font_class; ?>">
    <?php echo $div_string; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: To ensure that you'll get a "safe" size in most cases, be sure to base $random_number on the number of, say, M's that will fit within 100 pixels (as opposed to, say, i's ;-)). There are ways to do stuff like this accurately using javascript (iterate over font-sizes in a hidden div and measure its resulting width), but it's rather unseemly.

Comment: You shouldn't be embedding font sizes in server side code. Apply different classes and set the font size in the css.

Answer (score 1):

There is not a css way to do it you can use javascript or [text-overflow](http://www.css3.info/preview/text-overflow/) in css3